No power on just bled, prior working hydraulic brakes after putting them on new bike
EDIT - dec 29
Looks like the culprit was indeed the front caliper that due to the leak, lacked power and kept contaminating the pads / rotor.
Yesterday I installed a used Shimano M8000 front brake. While I didn't like much of the lever feel, there was a big improvement on braking. Still not like I expected. I blamed it on the brake needed a bleed.
Since I spent all my mineral oil on the previous brake, I took the bike to a decathlon shop where they did a lever bleed and extra cleaning / sanding of the rotor and pads.
After that, the wheel locked up while braking and it started to work like it should. Nothing to write home about, though. I expected a lot more of the deore xt name.
Needs more testing and bedding, but all indicates this is the right path.
Today will be the day for that.
Still I cannot explain why that brake worked ok when it was on bike A. Maybe it had better grip on the rotors and it was just about to fail.
Summary
2 bikes, bought new brakes for bike A, installed old but working hydraulic brakes from bike A on bike B.
After bleed and tight feel comes the test, front brake on bike B is unable to lock up the wheel while pushing the bike walking by its side, so almost no braking power.
I've tried many things but I can't make them work properly.
Problem present on both brakes, but far worse on front.
What can I do to make them work again?
Details
Low end bikes and brakes, not asking for miracles just for them to work decent for city riding like they used to on bike A or at least as previous brakes on bike B.
Bike B previously had mechanical disc brakes which I adjusted, they needed a little strength on the fingers but were able to stop the bike decently.
When bike A had the brakes I could stop fine from cruising speeds with one or two fingers and never needed to pull them hard. Front brake needed a bleed but it did work.
I bought new brakes for bike A because I wanted to try something a little better and at the same time upgrade the brakes on bike B.
Upon installation on bike B I realize they don't brake at all. I've never felt brakes so bad of any kind.
Front brake is almost non existent.
Rear brake works a little better but bad still.
Things I've tried

Changed the pads to the ones from the mechanical brake. Tried front and rear ones, same result
changed the pads to new Shimano ones, same result
sanded rotors and pads with fine grit metal sandpaper
cleaned rotors and pads with isopropyl alcohol
cleaned rotors and pads with acetone (after this the squeaking almost stopped)
baked pads on kitchen stove flame
tried bedding them as per sram video on YouTube

After the acetone cleaning step and the bedding , I'd say the braking improved a little but it's still far worse than the cheapest of no name rim brakes. I've never experienced worst braking.
Additional info
Brakes are, FRONT : Chinese brand (ANV o ALIV i think), REAR : Shimano MT200
New info (dec 26)
I think I've found the culprit. At least partially.
Today I removed and inspected the caliper and found one of the pads had a darker coloration.
One of the pistons was lazy from the beginning and while trying to exercise it I realized there's a tiny leak on one "side", like a tiny bursting bubble.
I think that explains the piston laziness, lack of power and coloration of the pads...
Still it worked while on bike A, that I can't explain.

Critical to diagnosis is lever feel and amount of travel - are the levers spongy of firm and are they hitting the handlebars, or only traveling a short distance.

Is your rim/wheel made for rim brakes? Or is it completely smooth?

As you wrote you changed pads to those from the mechanical brake and Shimano ones: are you sure they are interchangeable?

The squeaking and no power: oil contamination. New pads and thorough clean of rotors or replace. No other fix will work acceptably well.

Please confirm what kind of fluid you used during the bleed?  Shimano will use Mineral oil, I don't know what the other brake would use, maybe the same or maybe DOT brake fluid.  They are not interchangeable.

In addition to @Noise: it's important to do both steps at once: clean the rotors AND put in new pads. If you put in new pads on the oily rotor or brake on the cleaned rotor with oily pads, you will cross-contaminate the part that you just have cleaned or replaced. In that case it might look like you solved your problem but it will come back after some braking.

@mattnz lever feel is tight, not spongy. Short travel distance. Far from the handlebars. I if I wanted the levers to touch the handlebars, I'll need to bend them.

@Willeke I mentioned rim brakes as an example of braking power. My problem is with hydraulic disc brakes.

@BenediktBauer I'm not sure if they're interchangeable, they look the same type to me. I read that there's no difference for mechanical and hydraulic rotors, so I assumed pads would be the same. Still, I also tried Shimano pads for hydraulic brakes and the result was the same

@Criggie mineral oil. Both brakes have it written on them

@Noise & BenediktBauer I thought of contamination, but when using the mechanical calipers the bike would squeak but stop fine. Still, I sanded both rotors and pads (the ones that came with the caliper), then I also tried the previous pads on the mechanical caliper, then I put brand new pads. Then cleaned rotors with isopropyl alcohol (gunk detected) and lastly, at same time, cleaned rotors and pads with acetone (more gunk detected, but rubbed until no more ) and also baked the pads. This last step improved squeaking (lots) and braking (little) but still almost no braking power (no locking)
